# How to open special locations in windows explorer through command line?

Tags: cmd, windows-explorer

In Windows Explorer, there are some special locations besides local paths, such as This PC, Quick Access, Network, or **some remote location provided by net disks like OneDrive**.
For local paths, I can simply use "explorer [location]" in cmd to open them. As for those special locations, is there a way to **open them through command line**? If not provided, is it possible to **control Windows Explorer to navigate to these locations** from an external program after it's launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming Windows 10) You can use "explorer shell:[folderName]" from the command prompt, such as:

```
explorer shell:ThisPcDesktopFolder
```

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/shell-commands-to-access-the-special-folders/ has a good list.